# apache timeout and keepalive settings

Tags: apache

I run a apache webserver with some sites that gets 40-50k a day. have read a lot about keepalive when to turn this on and when to deactivate it.
The biggest benefit of keepalive on is that it reduces cpu usage, but disadvantage is that it can get a lot of connections open, i have sometimes 600 apache workers active on my dedicated server. When its turned off this is always around 320.

My main question is, what is best setting in my situation ?
The site contains around 90 requests for each visit, this are all images/js/css files. I have a     Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz, 16 cores with 16GB memory and my max workers is currently 500
The site has very big peaks in traffic, from 400 a hour to 7000 a hour around specific hours.

My current settings are
Timeout 45
Keepalive ON
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5